# usage of chown in following two cases

Tags: linux

I have seen two usages of chown that is used for changing file owner and group

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /data/db
```

What is the meaning of $USER:$USER

```
chown `id -u` /data/db
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix

what is the meaning of `id -u`

Comment: @larsmans, can you tell me how did you make it so that ` is displayed?

Comment: Escape it with "\", so "\'" within a code portion will display the `\``

Comment: I put four spaces before the commands. Backticks are used on SO to put code samples inline in text.

Comment: @birryree, I tried and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$USER` is an environment variable that always holds the username of the real or system user executing the command.  `id -u` returns the executing user's UID number.  `chown` will accept either the user name or UID.

```
# on my system here:

$ echo $USER
# michael

$ id -u
# 500
```

`$USER:$USER` is used to set ownership of the file/directory to the user as primary owner and the user's group as group owner.  Many Linux distributions create a dedicated group for each user.  To see yours,

```
cat /etc/group
```

Answer (score 1):

`$USER` is a variable that expands to the username of the user executing a command.

```
id -u
```

prints the user identification number (UID) of the current user.

```
chown `id -u` /data/db
```

runs the command `id -u`, takes its output (by the backquotes), and passes that to `chown` as the first argument, so ownership of `/data/db` is given to the user executing the command.

Answer (score 1):

the first $USER variable is the new owner and the 2nd is the new GROUP

`id -u` will be executed before your `chown` execution. it will give you the uid.